# Tables and Borders

Tags: html, css

I am having a little trouble getting tables and borders to work with css.

What I have been doing is taking the `<table id=usertable>` and putting on `border-width` and `border-style` on it.

Now what happens is the OUTside part of the border is the one being affected by the width and style. All the values and rows inside are not being affected by this. The only thing that will work is the color of the border. And the border had to be specify in HTML as `border=1` for some reason.

**CSS:**

```
#usertable {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**PHP**:

```
echo "<table id=usertable>
    <tr>
        <td id=usertable_top>ID</td>
        <td id=usertable_top>USERNAME</td>
        <td id=usertable_top>PASSWORD</td>
        <td id=usertable_top>EMAIL</td>
        <td id=usertable_top>ADMIN</td>
        <td id=usertable_top>ACTIONS</td>
    </tr>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$row[ID]</td>
                <td>$row[USERNAME]</td>
                <td>$row[PASSWORD]</td>
                <td>$row[EMAIL]</td>
                <td>$row[ADMINSTATUS]</td>
        ";
    if ($_SESSION[adminsts] == sadmin) {
        echo "
            <td>Make Admin</td>
        ";
    }
    echo "
        </tr>
    ";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Add some code, css, html

Comment: Add your html and css code

Comment: @DanteFaña great timing

Comment: @LironIlayev yeah XD

Comment: Why are you dumping PHP in there? Does it have any relevance? Why not just put the HTML there? For that matter, why not make it a  [live demo](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a border on a table will do exactly that.

If you want to set a border on a table cell, then you have to style the table cell.

```
td, th { 
    border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

Comment: What is and what does "th" do?

Comment: also how would i achieve the same function as border-collapse? I have it but it wont work.

Comment: Table header, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting the html in a wrong way. The id should be used once in the whole document (use class='yourclass' instead)

```
td.yourclass{} #to apply rules to the td's

th.yourclass{} #to apply rules to the th's

tr.yourclass{} #to apply rules to the tr's
```

or you can use an id='usertable' for the table and then access all the elements with

```
#usertable td{}

#usertable tr{}

#usertable th{}
```

Comment: Maybe th.className{}, td.className{}.

Comment: wht is the difference between td tr and th

Comment: tr is for the row. td for the cell and th is for the header. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp